# SSH and localhost

Tags: java, ssh, localhost, scp

Okay so, I have a java program that needs to be compiled and run on my university machine. I have been working on my laptop at home and I thought it would be simple:

1. Work on the files
2. scp it to my university machine
3. log in via ssh
4. run the script

Now everything is fine up to there. The script runs and the files compile however, the result is that it should display in the browser at http://localhost:4000/. I have been going to chrome and typing that it but it says: This webpage is not available. Do you know what I have to do?

Comment: You should probably use http://ip_you_just_used_for_ssh:4000/

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities.

First, you have to understand that `localhost` is always the current machine where a program is running. In this case, your browser. If the browser runs on the laptop, then it will look for the server to connect to on the laptop.

Possible solutions:

**Use a textual browser over ssh**

If the output you expect from your server is simple, many times you can use command-line utilities such as `wget`, `curl` or `lynx` to get it. If you are in an ssh session, `wget`, `curl` and `lynx` are running on your *server* rather than your laptop. Therefore, they will see `localhost` as the university server, and will bring you its output properly (provided, of course, that your program works properly).

**Use the server's IP**

If your program is running on your university server, and the IP address (if you're using a host name to connect, then the address that host name resolves to) you used to connect to it is the actual machine's address rather than a firewall's address, and the university firewall is not blocking access to port 4000 on that machine, you will probably be able to connect to your program using `http://address.of.university.server:4000/`.

**Use port forwarding**

One of the things `ssh` can do for you is port forwarding, meaning that anything that connects to port X on your laptop is directed to port Y on a machine accessible from your ssh target (the university machine). This way, you can set port 4000 on your laptop to go to port 4000 on the server, so your local browser will send its request to the laptop, but the running ssh session will forward that to the server. E.g.

```
ssh -L4000:localhost:4000 address.of.university.server
```

As long as this ssh session is running, you can connect to `http://localhost:4000` and the calls will got to the server running on port 4000 on your university machine.

Comment: Okay, so I tried http://address.of.university.server/4000 but it still says that the webpage is unavailable. Any ideas?

Comment: @codeav3 Sorry, it should have been `:` rather than `/`. I'll edit right away. But if that fails as well - the server may be behind a firewall and you'll need to use one of my other solutions.

Comment: okay so i tried again and this appeared in my browser:

Problem accessing /Witter/. Reason:

    Exception constructing service 'TimingFilter': Error invoking service builder method uk.ac.warwick.java.cs126.services.AppModule.buildTimingFilter(Logger) (at AppModule.java:88) (for service 'TimingFilter'): uk/ac/warwick/java/cs126/services/AppModule$1

with a long list below it of "caused by"

Comment: @codeav3 Well then, you succeeded in accessing your application, now you have to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

`localhost` refers to the local machine where your browser is running. If the site is to be served on the university server, then it will not be reachable from your laptop at `localhost`. You will need to use the IP/hostname of the server you deployed your files to, with port 4000.

Comment: but the hostname I SCP'd into has my user ID in it. In terminal, it then asks for my password

Comment: @codeav3 Try it without the user ID or password. The uid and pass apply specifically to the process of logging in over SSH and/or SCP and do not necessarily apply to HTTP.

Comment: just tried it and it still says webpage not available

Answer (score 0):

use specific ip address instead localhost and check whether your program is properly listening in 4000 port number by executing netstat -an | grep 4000